# XSLT Performance

Tags: performance, xslt

I am working for a project which has many XSLT transformations.
The transformations have to be as fast as possible.

For readability I wrote many of them dividing "business logic" and 
"output". For example

```
<!-- Business Logic -->
 <xsl:variable name="myLocalVar">
      <xsl:value-of select="func:whateverComputation(params)" />
</xsl:variable>

<!-- more buss logic here -->

<!-- Output -->
<xsl:element name="mytag">
    <xsl:value-of select="$myLocalVar" />
</xsl:element>
```

Of course this can be written in a compact form

```
<xsl:element name="mytag">
      <xsl:value-of select="func:whateverComputation(params)" />
</xsl:element>
```

Is the first form *slower* than the second one?

Comment: There's no way we can answer this. We don't even know what XSLT processor you are using. The only way to know for sure is to benchmark it yourself. (Also, putting business logic in your templates at all seems unwise.)

Comment: I agree with Avila. But please note your xsl:variable declaration exhibits a common error: change it to `<xsl:variable name='x' select='f:comp(params)'/>`. I've seen this change applied across a stylesheet give a 3-fold speed-up, not to mention making the code more concise and readable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Saving the result of function application to a variable isn't going to have any significant impact on performance** in the general case (and some XSLT processors such as Saxon use lazy evaluation, so the function will not be evaluated untill the variable is actually needed).

**On the contrary**, if the function must be evaluated more than once with the same parameters, saving the result in a variable *can* result in some cases in significant increase of efficiency.

**The correct way to improve performance is**:

1. Profile/measure to identify real bottlenecks.
2. Optimize only the biggest bottlenecks.
3. If there is still need for increased performance, start a new iteration, going to 1. above.

**To quote Donald Knuth**: "*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*" -- which is actually a paraphrase of the wellknown saying: "*The road to hell is paved with good intentions."*

Answer (score 16):

From a section of the [the XSLT FAQ](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect4/N9883.html):

## Few Points related to XSLT Performance:

1. `xsl:variables` are dynamic values. These variables are not in cache, and run every time that they are referenced in XSL. *Explicit type* casting of `xsl:variable` improves the performance. You can do type casting with `string()` and `boolean()` functions.

   For example:

   `<xsl:variable name="_attr" select="string( /node/child[ @attr ] )">`
2. Instead of using sub-elements, use attributes wherever possible. Using attributes instead of elements improves the performance. When performing XPath matches, attributes are faster because they are loosely typed. This makes validation of the schema easier.
3. When you match against attribute values, use enumerator attributes. Use multiple attribute names as bits, and set their values to true or false.

### Eight tips for how to use XSLT efficiently:

1. Keep the source documents small. If necessary split the document first.
2. Keep the XSLT processor (and Java VM) loaded in memory between runs
3. If you use the same stylesheet repeatedly, compile it first.
4. If you use the same source document repeatedly, keep it in memory.
5. If you perform the same transformation repeatedly, don't. Store the result instead.
6. Keep the output document small. For example, if you're generating HTML, use CSS.
7. Never validate the same source document more than once.
8. Split complex transformations into several stages.

### Eight tips for how to write efficient XSLT:

1. Avoid repeated use of "//item".
2. Don't evaluate the same node-set more than once; save it in a variable.
3. Avoid `<xsl:number>` if you can. For example, by using `position()`.
4. Use `<xsl:key>`, for example to solve grouping problems.
5. Avoid complex patterns in template rules. Instead, use `<xsl:choose>` within the rule.
6. Be careful when using the `preceding[-sibling]` or `following[-sibling]` axes. This often indicates an algorithm with n-squared performance.
7. Don't sort the same node-set more than once. If necessary, save it as a result tree fragment and access it using the `node-set()` extension function.
8. To output the text value of a simple `#PCDATA` element, use `<xsl:value-of>` in preference to `<xsl:apply-templates>`.

Comment: What is the benefit of splitting complex transformations into multiple stages? Better memory usage?

Comment: Transformations will happen faster and also it can be reused wherever it required

Comment: When you say 'reused' do you mean reused during processing or are you referring to modularity?

Comment: I'm slightly confused. You say "These variables are not in cache, and run every time that they are referenced in XSL", but also you say "Don't evaluate the same node-set more than once; save it in a variable". If I do `<xsl:variable name="items" select="//items" />` won't that be reevaluated every time?

Comment: if you use <xsl:variable select="./node"> then "./node" is evaluated for each use of the variable, however <xsl:variable select="string(./node)"> may cause the value to be cached in some xslt processors, see https://www.onenaught.com/posts/23/xslt-tips-for-cleaner-code-and-better-performance

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the game, but I thought I'd share this link: [Techniques to Improve Performance of XSL Transformations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815124).

Comment: Quoth the raven: 404.