# How to profile executions of Saxon

Tags: performance, xslt, profiling, saxon

In the spirit of [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev)'s answer at [XSLT Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398953/xslt-performance/9399668#9399668), I want to create a profile that shows where the time consumed by my XSL transform has gone. Using the Saxon -TP:profile.html option, we created an “Analysis of Stylesheet Execution Time” HTML document.

At the top of that document, we see:

```
Total time: 1102316.688 milliseconds
```

This figure (1,102 seconds) corresponds with my measured program execution time.

However, the sum of the “total time (net)” column values is less than 2% of this total. I assume, per http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/performanceanalysis.html, that the “total time (net)” column values are reported in milliseconds.

I would normally work a profile from the top down, but in this case, I don’t want to invest effort into optimizing a template that is reported to have contributed less than 0.5% of my total response time.

How can I find out where my time has really gone? Specifically, how can I learn where the unreported 98% of my program's time has been consumed?

Comment: Interesting: I haven't seen that effect before. Do the gross timings shed any light? Is the gross time for the entry template (usually match="/") anywhere close to the overall elapsed time? I think I would investigate by looking at the Java profile: knowing where the Java VM is spending its time should shed light on why it's escaping the XSLT-level instrumentation.

Comment: @MichaelKay, my top-level template indeed is the row with the largest “total time (gross)” value, but that value is only 5,370.080 milliseconds, which is still less than 0.5% of my total execution time. When you mention “the Java profile,” are you referring to Java Mission Control? We're new to JVM profiling, so any advice will be warmly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: (a) I think a possible explanation is this: when -TP is used, the code is run with tracing enabled, and when tracing is enabled, global variables are evaluated eagerly before entering the first template rule. The execution times for the global variables are not included in the profile unless they invoke functions or templates. Perhaps you have a global variable that takes a long time to evaluate, perhaps because of a call on doc() or some complex path expression?

Comment: (b) By Java profile I mean the output of -Xrunhprof:cpu=samples, or the output of VisualJVM showing which methods account for the most time, and where they are called from.

Comment: We do have global variables that don't invoke functions or templates. Big, complicated ones. Thank you for the Java profiling tip. The image of our target is forming...

Comment: (It would be a Beautiful Thing for the profiler to identify the duration of each of these global variable evaluations.)

Comment: Yes indeed. I'll log it as a requirement.

Comment: See https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2319#change-4051. O'Neil called in sick this morning, but this challenge seems to have revived him...

Comment: Here's how we found and fixed our problem. As @MichaelKay suggested, our problem was indeed within a complex global variable definition. We isolated which definition it was by, one variable at a time, branching around the complex calculation and assigning a constant tree value. We did this for each variable in turn until we measured a response time plummet. This isolated the problem to about 50 lines of code. From there, we replaced complicated expressions with constant values, one expression at a time, until we isolated the offending line. ...The brute-force "repeat until #win" strategy.