# XSLT - Converting a string to a node-set, or find a creative alternative

Tags: xml, xslt

So, first of all, I know the quick answer to my question: not possible. I know the slightly longer answer, use the document() function to load it from an external resource. I've taken that approach, and it works very well. However, performance is not that great, and performance is a requirement of this project, so I'm searching for a better way.

The project is simple, mostly. Use XSLT 1.0 to merge two XML documents. Both documents have the same schema, one represents old data, the other new data. The final document should have the full schema of the old data document, but any values contained in the new data document should have replaced the old data.

I can't provide the actual code, because the data being handled is proprietary, but here are some examples to show what I'm talking about:

Old Data XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Field1>OldValue1</Field1>
    <Field2>OldValue2</Field2>
    <Field3>OldValue3</Field3>
    <Field4>OldValue4</Field4>
    <Field5>OldValue5</Field5>
</Document>
```

New Data XML. Notice how only two fields have values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Field3>NewValue3</Field3>
    <Field5>NewValue5</Field5>
</Document>
```

Final XML, with the new data merged in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Field1>OldValue1</Field1>
    <Field2>OldValue2</Field2>
    <Field3>NewValue3</Field3>
    <Field4>NewValue5</Field4>
    <Field5>OldValue5</Field5>
</Document>
```

So, like I said, loading the new data document from an external filepath works fine, but it degrades performance, and since the final files we are going to be working with will likely be massive in size, performance matters.

The application my company has, that actually executes this transformation, provides some handy magical ways to get String values defined in-memory into the XSLT. The problem is getting the XSLT to then recognize that String as a document.

I've tried everything I can find online, and I keep coming up empty. Any assistance that can be provided would be awesome. I just feel stumped right now.

Can I convert a String to a node-set (It'll always be well-formed XML)? Or is there some other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Find out which XSLT processor you use and check its API on the type of parameters it allows and the way you can implement extension functions. Parsing a string of XML into a tree of nodes is easy with many platforms and XSLT processors, but it is processor and platform specific.

Comment: I have a hard time to believe that one document()  call should impact the performance  that badly. I would expect that the merging will take most of the time (if both files are big), especially if you don't use keys in the right way (What we can't know). It should be easily to check what the time benefit is, with a test xml containing both xml files.

Comment: Can you clarify about how keys will improve performance? I'm currently just doing an identity transform, with specific templates looking for certain fields and determining if they need to be replaced.

Comment: @user2223059 That will depend on your real input. If your xml looks really like your example, keys will  not help either. This was only a guess, (as yours as  about the document() function?). I would suggest start with analyzing your  performance issue.  E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9399413/2115381